# How do I simplify the equilibrium point to this simplified expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Install the following package:

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", 
 "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]

<< EcoEvo`
```

The code:

```
SetModel[{Pop[pop] -> {
    Component[
      s] :> {Equation :> \[Nu] - \[Beta]1 i2 s  - \[Beta]2 j s - \
\[Mu] s},
    Component[
      i1] -> {Equation :>  
       p \[Beta]1 i2 s + q \[Beta]2 j s - b1 i1 + \[Xi]1 j }, 
    Component[
      i2] -> {Equation :>  (1 - p) \[Beta]1 i2 s + (1 - 
           q) \[Beta]2 j s + \[Epsilon] i1 - b2 i2 + \[Xi]2 j }, 
    Component[j] -> {Equation :> p1 i2 - b3 j },
    Component[a] -> {Equation :> p2 j  - b4 a}}, 
  Parameters :> {\[Nu] > 0, \[Beta]1 > 0, \[Beta]2 > 0, \[Mu] > 0, 
    p > 0, q > 0, b1 > 0, b2 > 0, b3 > 0, b4 > 0, 
    p1 > 0, \[Epsilon] > 0}}]
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

where

```
 r0 = ((\[Beta]1 b3 (\[Epsilon] p + 
          b1 (1 - p)) + \[Beta]2 p1 (\[Epsilon] q + 
          b1 (1 - q))) (\[Nu]/\[Mu]))/(b1 b2 b3 - (\[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 +
         b1 \[Xi]2) p1);
```

We obtain our equilibrium points:

```
{{s -> \[Nu]/\[Mu], i1 -> 0, i2 -> 0, j -> 0, 
  a -> 0}, {s -> (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
    b1 p1 \[Xi]2)/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
    b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
    p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]), 
  i1 -> (-b2 b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - b2 b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - 
      b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 - 
      p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + 
      b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]2 + p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]2 + (
      b2 b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b2 b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 +
          b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]2 (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]2 (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 +
          b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 \[Beta]1 - 
      b1 b2 b3 p1 \[Beta]2 + b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + 
      b1 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2), 
  i2 -> (-b1 b3^2 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + b1 b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - 
      b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + b1 b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - 
      b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
      b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
      b1 b3^2 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b3^2 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b3 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 \[Beta]1 - 
      b1 b2 b3 p1 \[Beta]2 + b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + 
      b1 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2), 
  j -> (-b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + b1 b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - 
      b1 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + b1 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - 
      b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
      p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
      b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b1 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b3 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 \[Beta]1 - 
      b1 b2 b3 p1 \[Beta]2 + b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 b3 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + 
      b1 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2), 
  a -> (-b1 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + b1 b3 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - 
      b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + b1 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - 
      b3 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
      p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
      b1 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 b3 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 +
          b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) - (
      b1 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
         b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - 
       b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      b3 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]) + (
      p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 + 
         p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + b1 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 \[Beta]1 + 
       b1 b3 p \[Beta]1 - b1 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 p1 q \[Beta]2 - 
       b3 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
       p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 - 
      b1 b2 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2)}}
```

These are long and tedious. Is there a way to simplify them using each other and `r0`?

For example; why does i2 = $\frac{b_3}{p_1} j$?

Comment: Is this a question about Mathematica? or the Wolfram Language? If you include the points (or representative data) and the Mma code that you have tried out so far for the simplification that you have alluded to, then this question will likely be considered valid and on-topic given that you can also describe where you are having difficulty. As posed, this question is asking the potential respondents to read a scientific paper. I would request you to edit your post further.

Comment: @Syed I edited the question.

Comment: The situation has almost not changed. Now the respondents are being asked to install and understand the workings of a package related to the scientific paper. Maybe someone who has prior experience with this package would take up this question. You will have to wait and see. Why not contact the author of the paper directly? Best of luck.

Comment: It isn't a difficult task to install the package to be honest. You just copy, paste and shift+ enter. All I ask is for example why is i2, obtained from our equilibrium point equal to $\frac{b_3}{p_1} j$? What simplification can we do to achieve this result?

Comment: @rhermans You don't require the link to answer the question since I edited the question. Let me further edit it. Please have a look now. I linked the paper as a reference in case one asked "how did you get this simplified expression?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eqPts` is the equilibrium points in your question. Start by using [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
LeafCount /@ {eqPts, eqPts2 = eqPts // Simplify}

(* {1958, 448} *)
```

The variables are

```
vars = Variables[Level[eqPts2, {-1}]]

(* {a, b1, b2, b3, b4, i1, i2, j, p, p1, p2, q, s, β1, β2, \
ϵ, μ, ν, ξ1, ξ2} *)
```

Convert the replacement rules in `eqPts2` into the corresponding equations

```
eqns = eqPts2 /. Rule :> Equal;
```

With five equations you can [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for one variable while eliminating four variables.

```
sol = Solve[#, i2, {s, i1, a, b1}] & /@ eqns

(* {{}, {{i2 -> (b3 j)/p1}}} *)
```

The expected result,

```
sol[[2, 1, 1]] /. Rule :> Equal

(* i2 == (b3 j)/p1 *)
```

Verifying this relation at both equilibrium points,

```
% /. eqPts2 // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

**EDIT:** A more general approach will be **much slower**

```
vars = eqns[[1, All, 1]]

(* {s, i1, i2, j, a} *)

params = Complement[Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]], vars]

(* {b1, b2, b3, b4, p, p1, p2, q, β1, β2, ϵ, μ, ν, ξ1, ξ2} *)

solve[solveVar_Symbol, var_Symbol] :=
 SortBy[
   Union[
    Simplify[
     Solve[eqns[[2]], solveVar, #] & /@
       (Append[Complement[vars,
            {solveVar, var}], #] & /@
         params) /. {} :> Nothing]],
   LeafCount][[1, 1]]
```

To `Solve` for `i2` in terms of `j`

```
solve[i2, j]

(* {i2 -> (b3 j)/p1} *)
```

To `Solve` for `i2` in terms of `j`

```
solve[i1, j] // Apart

(* {i1 -> (j (b3 p β1 + p1 q β2) ν)/(
   b1 (b3 j β1 + j p1 β2 + p1 μ)) + (j ξ1)/b1} *)
```

You could then generalize this to solve for a variable in terms of each of the other variables and select the simplest form; however, this would be **very slow**.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I edit the extra parts(the other components) to see if you can simplify them too?

Comment: You now have an approach, try to apply it to your other relations. If you encounter a problem that you cannot solve with reasonable effort, post a new question showing what you have tried and the problems that you are having.

Comment: I will try, thank you.

Comment: I forgot to ask; will this work without knowing the "simplified expression" beforehand? So a better example would've been the one I commented on Chris' answer.

Comment: I tried your edited version, it doesn't seem to work.. at least on my computer. can you post the full code?

Comment: I'm very interested in the second example i.e. the one involving `i1` in terms of `j`

Comment: The full code is there. Try starting with a fresh kernel. Use `eqPts` from your question; `eqPts2` and `eqns` from my initial response; and `vars`, `params`, and `solve` from the edit.

Comment: Everything works, apart from this `solve[solveVar_Symbol, var_Symbol] :=
 SortBy[
   Union[
    Simplify[
     Solve[eqns[[2]], solveVar, #] & /@
       (Append[Complement[vars,
            {solveVar, var}], #] & /@
         params) /. {} :> Nothing]],
   LeafCount][[1, 1]]`. when I run the latter and try `solve[i2, j]`, it gives a wrong output.

Comment: Ok, starting a fresh kernel fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: why isn't this working for a different system?

Answer (score 3):

$i_2 = \frac{b_3}{p_1} j$ follows directly from setting ${dj \over dt}=0$.  You could do that manually, or in `EcoEvo`, give `SolveEcoEq` a list of variables to solve for and use `QSS -> True` (otherwise non-specified variables will be assumed equal to zero).

```
SolveEcoEq[{j}, QSS -> True]
(* {{j -> (i2 p1)/b3}} *)
```

You might also try:

```
SolveEcoEq[{a}, QSS -> True]
(* {{a -> (j p2)/b4}} *)
```

The others don't seem particularly useful.

Sorry, I don't know of any easy way to rearrange in terms of `r0`.

Comment: I completely overlooked the equation $j$ and this would give the result directly as stated. Now however, a better example would be why does $$ i_1 = \frac{1}{b_1}\left[p \beta_1 \frac{\nu b_3}{(\beta_1 b_3+\beta_2 p_1)J^*+\mu p_1}+q \beta_2 \frac{\nu p_1}{(\beta_1 b_3+\beta_2 p_1)J^*+\mu p_1} +\xi_1\right]J^*$$

Comment: Mathematica's good at solving equations, but not necessarily putting the solution in the form that makes intuitive sense.  That might still require human intervention!

Comment: Essentially we are selecting one component and describing the rest using this component, I think Mathematica should be able to do it! if you have a look at this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258344/simplifying-the-following-expression we see most of components are in terms of the $J^*$ component.

Comment: I'll be curious to see what other people come up with.  Anyhow, sometimes you gain more intuitive understanding about a model by pushing through the algebra by hand, rather than relying on Mathematica.  I recommend using the two together.